# npm CLI with semantic versioning that includes > (greater than) symbol

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

Playing around with [npm](/questions/tagged/npm)'s [semver](http://semver.npmjs.com), most of it seems to translate well to the npm CLI, e.g.:

```
npm install somepackage@~1.0.0-rc
```

... will include everything greater than the 1.0 version in the same minor range.

But to include a greater than symbol, e.g.:

```
npm install somepackage@>=1.0.0-rc
```

...it blows up the shell because it thinks I'm trying to output to file. I tried wrapping the version in quotes and several other options but to no avail.

Comment: Use a backslash to escape the >

Comment: Yeah, I got that  Just answered and posted it because it might help someone later. Also - for what it's worth, you should NEVER gain or lose reputation. 1337 FTW.

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough, I wasn't really thinking about escaping characters in the shell. Escaping with `\` works:

```
npm install somepackage@\>=1.0.0-rc
```